# Rails4, getting all (multi-level) comments with their authors and authors rating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations, rails-activerecord

Having models:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base   
  has_many :comments
  has_many :ratings
end

# self join to unable multilevel comments
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :upcomment, class_name: "Comment"
  belongs_to :user
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings
  has_many :comments
end
```

when i wan't to get all comments with their replies and comments/replies authors I do following query:

```
@comments = Comment
  .where('comments.movie_id = ? AND comments.upcomment_id IS NULL', params[:movie])
  .includes([:user, :replies => :user])
```

**Q1:** But how should I modify this query to includes also user rating for each comment and reply?.

### My attempts

For now I'll skip replies for simplicity. I added ratings to .includes and where clause as follows:

```
@comments = Comment
  .where('comments.movie_id = ? AND comments.upcomment_id IS NULL', params[:movie]) 
  .includes([:user => :ratings])
  .where(ratings: { movie_id: params[:movie] })
```

It works, but it returns only those comments which author has a rating. When I looked at the SQL generated by Rails I noticed that '"ratings"."movie_id" = ?' is (probably) in the wrong place:

```
SELECT [...]
LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" "users" ON "users"."id" = "comments"."user_id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "ratings" "users_ratings" ON "ratings"."user_id" = "users"."id" 
WHERE (comments.movie_id = '131' AND comments.upcomment_id IS NULL) AND "ratings"."movie_id" = 131

| So I changed and made a query in SQLite to check if it works
V
SELECT [...]
LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "comments"."user_id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "ratings" ON "ratings"."user_id" = "users"."id" AND "ratings"."movie_id" = "comments"."movie_id"
WHERE (comments.movie_id = '131' AND comments.upcomment_id IS NULL)
```

It seems to work, but 
**Q2:** How can I perform join with more than one condition in Rails (without writing join by myself) ?

Since I didn't find answer for above question I wrote these joins by myself. I had to add eager_load to make it work and ended up with follwoing query:

```
@comments = Comment
  .where('comments.movie_id = ? AND comments.upcomment_id IS NULL', params[:movie]) 
  .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN "comments" "replies_comments" ON "replies_comments"."upcomment_id" = "comments"."id"')
  .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" "users_replies_comments" ON "users_replies_comments"."id" = "replies_comments"."user_id"')
  .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN "ratings" "ratings_users_replies_comments" ON "ratings_users_replies_comments"."user_id" = "users_replies_comm    ents.id" AND "ratings_users_replies_comments"."movie_id" = "comments"."movie_id"')
  .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" "users_comments" ON "users_comments"."id" = "comments"."user_id"')
  .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN "ratings" "ratings_users_comments" ON "ratings_users_comments"."user_id" = "users_comments"."id" AND "ratings_    users_comments"."movie_id" = "comments"."movie_id"')
  .eager_load([:replies => { :user => :ratings }, :user => :ratings])
```

It seems to work but I think it may be performance killer. So my last idea  was to load all comments with authors/replies and iterate over it, gather all authors ids and make additional query with "IN(id1,id2,...)". Then pass it to the view as a separate variable. Something like this:

```
 ids = @comments.map { |c| c.user.id }
 @comments.each { |c| c.replies.map { |r| ids.push r.user.id } }
 ids.uniq!

 @ratings = Rating
   .where('movie_id = ?', params[:movie])
   .where('user_id IN(?)', ids)
```

Or mayby I shouldn't simply do anything and make Rails to lazy load ratings when they will be needed? What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

So, ratings are not the same as comments, right? Why not? Make comment act as a (optional) rating too and remove the ratings table and model. This requires adding a rating score to comment and making comment body optional. Then you only need to load all comments for a movie.

Don't worry about a query to pre-load all the threaded child comments. You Worry about that when you have a few million comments. You should add the id of the top-most 'adam/eve' comment to every child, grandchild etc, so you can quickly load all the descendents in one query. You can also add the movie_id, so that you can put that in an index and quickly load every comment for a movie no matter how deep.

Also, cache the movie's total rating score in the movie table - when creating or updating a rating. Then you can show a list of movies with ratings without doing a COUNT for each request.